# which type of filter can we use to remove gravity from an accelerometer

Tags: filter, accelerometer, gravity, acceleration

Context:

i have an dispositif which contains an accelerometer. Due this acceleromter, i obtain acceleration in 3 axis . if my dispositif is stable, it gives me : 
 accel x: 0;
 accel y: 0;
 accel z: 9,8 ( gravity)

when we move the Dispositif, the gravity spreads in 3 axis . As far as we know , tha acceleration is the sum bewtenn dynamic acceleration (due mouvement) and static acceleration (gravity).

my goal is to remove static acceleration (gravity).

My question can i use high pass filter ? or exist other tpe of filter which can remove the gravity?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are stuck with a device without gyroscopes, there is no significantly better approach. The high-pass filter will work miserably because the acceleration can change as fast as you can rotate the device. But as I said before, without gyros, there is not much you can do...

Comment: thanks for your response. i have an gyroscope but the problem that my supervisor told me that accelerometer is reasonable to remove gravity. in this case, sure i should return to my gyroscope. the question here , if i will combine the acceleration+ gyro, i should use complementary filter or high pass filter is perfect to filter the gravity? thanks in advance

Comment: I have used [Direction Cosine Matrix IMU: Theory](http://gentlenav.googlecode.com/files/DCMDraft2.pdf) which is basically a tutorial how to do it. The method proposed in it is simple to implement and surprisingly robust.